# Count variable on a Variable R

Tags: r, count

```
Tid <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4)
Uid <- c(10,10,11,11,12,13,10,14)

Data <- data.frame(Tid,Uid)
```

I would like to know how many different Uid appear on every Tid.
My Results should look something like this.

```
Tid, freqUid 
1, 1
2, 2
3, 1
4, 2
```

I tried to use count on it but had some issues to use it on more then just one variable.

Comment: Answers below are great. Extra care how you deal with NA values. Eg. If you have something like `Tid <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4);
Uid <- c(10,10,11,NA,12,13,10,14);
Data <- data.frame(Tid,Uid)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With base R

```
as.data.frame(table(unique(Data)$Tid))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    2
# 3    3    1
# 4    4    2
```

Or (though the column name is less informative)

```
aggregate(Uid ~ Tid, unique(Data), length)
#   Tid Uid
# 1   1   1
# 2   2   2
# 3   3   1
# 4   4   2
```

---

The basic idea here is to only operate on the unique combinations of `Tid/Uid` and then count the different `Tid` instances

---

Edit:
per @nicolas comment, we can add `tapply` too here as a possible solution

```
as.data.frame.table(tapply(Data$Uid, Data$Tid, function(x) length(unique(x))))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    2
# 3    3    1
# 4    4    2
```

Comment: Or also `tapply(Data$Uid,Data$Tid,function(x) length(unique(x)))`, just to add another option in `base` R.

Comment: @nicola thanks :) its the same as `table(unique(Data)$Tid)`. I'm not sure if OP will be satisfied with that output though

Comment: Yes,  and you can apply the `table` method of `as.data.frame`: `as.data.frame.table(tapply(Data$Uid,Data$Tid,function(x) length(unique(x))))` and we are there. The comment was just to let the reader aware of the `tapply` function.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll add it.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `n_distinct` from `dplyr`.  We group by 'Tid', and get the `n_distinct` for 'Uid' within `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
   group_by(Tid) %>%
   summarise(freqUid=n_distinct(Uid))
#    Tid freqUid
#   (dbl)   (int)
#1     1       1
#2     2       2
#3     3       1
#4     4       2
```

---

Or we can use `uniqueN` from `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Data)`), grouped by 'Tid', we get the `uniqueN` of 'Uid'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(Data)[, list(freqUid=uniqueN(Uid)), by = Tid]
#  Tid freqUid
#1:   1       1
#2:   2       2
#3:   3       1
#4:   4       2
```

#### Benchmarks

Here are some benchmarks using a big dataset

```
set.seed(24)
Data <- data.frame(Tid=rep(1:1e4, each=100),
       Uid= sample(10:70, 1e4*100, replace=TRUE))
f1 <- function() as.data.frame.table(with(Data, 
          tapply(Uid, Tid, function(.) length(unique(.)))))
f2 <- function() as.data.frame(table(unique(Data)$Tid))
f3 <- function() aggregate(Uid ~ Tid, unique(Data), length)
f4 <- function() Data %>% 
                    group_by(Tid) %>% 
                    summarise(freqUid=n_distinct(Uid))
f5 <- function() as.data.table(Data)[, list(freqUid=uniqueN(Uid)), by = Tid]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), times=20L, unit='relative')
#Unit: relative
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#f1()  2.357808  2.506813  2.347543  2.401787  2.138740  2.706053    20 a 
#f2() 10.581284 11.798583 11.456316 11.975014 11.411718 10.664648    20 b
#f3() 28.243538 27.740333 25.630334 25.042240 25.590332 23.426749    20 c
#f4()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    20 a
#f5()  1.385114  1.369170  1.396271  1.405275  1.354914  1.473114    20 a
```

If we remove the `as.data.frame` in `f1` and `f2` (the output format will be different), and run the benchmarks again.

```
  f1 <- function() with(Data, tapply(Uid, Tid, function(.) length(unique(.))))
  f2 <- function() table(unique(Data)$Tid)
```

and as @DavidArenburg mentioned, `uniqueN` is slower compared to `length(unique(.))`.  So, replacing that in `f5`

```
 f5 <- function() as.data.table(Data)[, list(freqUid=length(unique(Uid))),
                                    by = Tid]

 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), times=20L, unit='relative')
 #Unit: relative
 #expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval  cld
 #f1()  3.466328  3.052508  2.789366  2.968971  3.069631  1.7850643    20  b  
 #f2() 11.539920 13.372543 12.067983 13.266105 13.014644  7.6774925    20   c 
 #f3() 33.491446 30.839725 27.339148 30.888726 29.953344 17.3956850    20    d
 #f4()  1.254533  1.177933  1.083263  1.213019  1.162862  0.6981573    20 a   
 #f5()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000    20 a
```

Comment: Where's is `data.table`? :( Also, probably take out `as.data.frame` from `f2 ` or add it to `f1`, not sure which.

Comment: I know, this is why I suggested to run it without it if we want to compare against `tapply` or to adjust `tapply` accordingly

Comment: @DavidArenburg Did you mean to add `as.data.frame` to `f1`?

Comment: or remove it from `f2`, whatever.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Removing it will give results in a different format though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I will update with both the versions.

Comment: Also maybe worth running benchmark on `setDT` an a copy of the data instead of `as.data.table`. Also, try `length(unique())` instead of `uniqueN` as it slower (there is a issue on GH regarding it)

Comment: @DavidArenburg It could be faster, but there is a bias as the subsequent runs will be fast.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Updated the benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in another dplyr-flavored approach:

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(Data) %>% count(Tid)
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#  Tid n
#1   1 1
#2   2 2
#3   3 1
#4   4 2
```

(Not suggesting this to be faster than other dplyr/data.table solutions.)

---

re @David's comment, all proposed solutions get to basically the same result. But of course, my suggestion is *not* identical with `table(unique(Data)$Tid)`. It's faster and returns a data.frame (not a `table` object).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
library(functional)
by(Uid, Tid, FUN=Compose(unique, length))
```

or base `R` as @David Arenburg underlined:

```
by(Uid, Tid, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Comment: Or just `by(Uid, Tid, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))` :P, but +1 for the most original answer here

Comment: well reason for `Compose` is I try to make concise and 'speaking' code (not necessarily an asset since it is subjective and I use packages..)

Comment: Maybe then explain what `Compose` does as I have no idea. I also wonder if this should be wrapped into `do.call(rbind...`

Comment: it just chain several functions into a single one, like a mathematical operator!